# How to copy OpenGL buffer when using double buffering?

Tags: c++, opengl

I am using double buffering in my OpenGL code, and ::SwapBuffers in order to flash frame.
I want to find a way to copy everything from the front buffer (which is now on the screen) to the back buffer (which I use to draw to) before starting drawing.
What is the simplest way to do it? Just simple pixel-pixel copy function.

Comment: It seems what you really want is called "copy-swap", where the back buffer is copied to the front buffer without changing the contents of the back buffer. I can tell you how to do this in Windows, but on other platforms I'm not sure.

Comment: Ok. That is something.